# Chart Title on Chart Click Event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What I would like is the ability to click the title of a chart and have an action take place however the next best thing was the click event at the chart level.  I was able to locate the title of the chart from the event using the following:

```
this.title.element.innerHTML
this.title.element.innerText
this.title.element.childNodes[0].nodeValue
this.title.element.firstChild.data
this.title.element.firstChild.nodeValue
```

While all of the above work in IE8+ they do no work in FireFox.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can set useHTML as true for title:

```
 title: {
    text: 'testtest',
 }
```

and then use jquery event click

```
$('.highcharts-title').click(function(){
    alert('action');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/puhtu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts has built in support for URLs in the title, so you can embed an "a href=" into the title of the chart to get it to load a page, for instance.

See: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Title/Add_hyper_link_to_chart_sub_title.htm

The page that you load can do whatever you want it to do.

What is nice about this approach is that if you have 10 charts on the same page, each chart can load a different URL.

I used this to navigate from a summary chart to a page with more detailed information.

Comment: It works but the problem is that it doesn't respect target="_blank" and without that it's almost useless to me.